# Setting and reading script-wide variables in Gradle

Tags: groovy, gradle

In my Gradle script `build.gradle` I want to do something like this:

```
String releaseDir = "release"
String prepareReleaseDir(String dir=releaseDir) {
    delete dir
    mkdir dir
}

task t() << {
    prepareReleaseDir()
}
```

But calling task `t` via Gradle raises this error message:

*> Could not find property 'releaseDir' on project ...*

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [extra properties](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html) (see section 13.4.2 of the user guide)

```
ext {
    releaseDir = 'release'
}
```